# Can I use RSpec to mock stdin/stdout to test console reads & writes?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stdout, stdin

My Ruby program reads lines from `stdin` and uses `puts` to print to `stdout` (the terminal). Can I use RSpec to test the reads and writes? Can I inject a string to my program like it was written in `stdin` and at the same time check the output?

```
line = STDIN.read.chomp.split
```

Also, I have the reads and writes in a loop, until `line[0]` is "quit". Can I test while the loop is running or should I call `subject.read_in` and `subject.write_out`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use mocks and have the method called more than once by listing multiple values in the `and_return()` method. These will be returned, one on each call, in the order given.

```
STDIN.should_receive(:read).and_return("Your string")

STDIN.should_receive(:read).and_return("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

You can do similar things with STDOUT:

```
STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("string")
```

See the [RSpec mocking documentation](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html) for more information.

Comment: It's `STDOUT.should_receive(:print)` actually.

Comment: how do you even know to use :print or :read....where does this exist in the "how to use RSpec" documentation? everywhere I turn I see expectations I've never heard of (I own the RSpec book) I can not find a definitive text on this subject.

Comment: @thefonso `print` and `read` are methods on STDOUT and STDIN respectively. They are nothing to do with RSpec. If you don't understand this I would *strongly* encourage you to spend some time studying Ruby separately from RSpec or any other library.

Comment: There's a good post on what's wrong with having expectations like these here: http://ngauthier.com/2010/12/everything-that-is-wrong-with-mocking.html

Answer (score 2):

## RSpec 3.0+

With RSpec 3.0, there is [output matcher](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#new-output-matcher) for this purpose:

```
expect { my_method }.to output("my message").to_stdout
expect { my_method }.to output("my error").to_stderr
```