# which version of RSpec does the expectation "should_receive" belong to?

Tags: rspec

here is a link to an overflow question that holds an example of this ...

[Can I use RSpec to mock stdin/stdout to test console reads & writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335282/testing-with-stdin-and-stdout-in-rspec)

example of "should_receive "
For the life of me I can't find a definitive guide for RSpec. please help.

I own "The RSpec" book from pragmatic...but I keep finding examples of expectations on the internet that don't exist in the RSpec books text. I've looked at the github/rspec for a reference text...relishapps.com....rubydocs....none of these give a definitive list of all expectations. They all only seem to have sets of examples. I'm hunting for something definitive.

Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`should_recieve` is in the RSpec book in the chapter on Mocks (page 183 and onwards).

Is there more you can't find?